# Play framework default tmp folder path

Tags: scala, playframework

What is the default path for tmp files? For example after uploading file to server, playframework puts them to tmp folder. Which folder uses playframework? I couldn't find any documentation. If I know this tmp folder path then I can use it to retrieve tmp files.
I'm using playframework 2.6 version.

**Edit**: added `scala` tag

Answer (score 4):

By default Play uses a class called `play.api.libs.Files.DefaultTemporaryFileCreator` to create its files. This class uses `java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory("playtemp")` to create its temporary directory. I don't think you can get the location of this directory very easily.

You can override the `TemporaryFileCreator` and provide your own logic by using dependency injection ([Java](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection), [Scala](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection)) to inject your own implementation.

If you just want to get access to the files that are uploaded then you do have access to the underlying temporary file during the request anyway. In the Java API just call `MultipartFormData.getFiles`; in the Scala API call `MultipartFormData.file("name")`. These calls will give you a `FilePart`. In Java the `File` is stored in the `FilePart`'s `file` field; in Scala it's in the `ref` property.

Comment: Thank for useful information. My case like this: user uploads file to Server A. Then Server A sends this temp file name to Server B. Then Server B starts downloading this temp file from Server A by name. So I validate this temp file name in Server A and get this file from temp files folder. I don't like to send full file path to Server B. Because it's hard to validate (security check) file path in Server A.

Comment: I'd recommend you access the file created during the upload and move it to a separate directory using your own naming system. That way you can control names however you like (e.g. use random numbers or UUIDs). Moving the file to a separate directory will also stop Play from cleaning up the temporary file when your action finishes executing. I think Play cleans up files when their `TemporaryFile` is garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering how to override the `DefaultTemporaryFileCreator` binded to trait `TemporaryFileCreator` of Play.

## Create your own implementation

```
package modules

import java.io.File

import javax.inject.{ Inject, Singleton }
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
import play.api.libs.Files.DefaultTemporaryFileCreator

@Singleton
class CustomTemporaryFileCreator @Inject() (applicationLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle)
  extends DefaultTemporaryFileCreator(applicationLifecycle) {

  override def create(prefix: String, suffix: String): File = {

    val file = super.create(prefix, suffix)
    file.setReadable(true, false)
    file
  }

}
```

## Create your own application Module, extending the built-in module provided by Play.

You will need to filter the build-in binding you want to replace, and then add your override, otherwise there will be 2 bindings for the same trait and the injector will complain.

```
package modules

import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}
import play.api.inject.{Binding, BuiltinModule}
import play.api.libs.Files

class MyAppModule extends BuiltinModule {

  override def bindings(env: Environment, configuration: Configuration): Seq[Binding[_]] = {
    val overrides = List(
      bind[Files.TemporaryFileCreator].to[CustomTemporaryFileCreator]
    )

    def isOverride(binding: Binding[_]): Boolean = overrides.exists(_.key.clazz == binding.key.clazz)

    overrides ++ super.bindings(env,configuration).filterNot(isOverride)
  }

}
```

## Replace existing build-in module by your own module

```
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.inject.BuiltinModule"
play.modules.enabled += "modules.MyAppModule"
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating a sample file using the Java `java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile` method

```scala
// Inside a Scala worksheet

import java.nio.file.Files
import java.io.File

val sampleFile: File = Files.createTempFile("sample", ".txt").toFile
println(sampleFile.getPath)
```

printing out the `path` of the file showed this on macOS:

```
/var/folders/jp/1sslmypy5thyn7wv8lfq1s3c0000gq/T/sample6927805051598358327.txt
```

This is probably a varying directory for each run of the application.

Therefore, if the full path is required during runtime, `getPath` is a viable option to get it.